# Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/npx'

Tags: npm, terminal

I tried to install npm install -g npm to update and I don't know if it was necessary but it failed. How do I give it permission to unlink?

[image]

Comment: The error is stating the obvious; the command does not have permission to unlink `/usr/local/bin/npx`.

Comment: What's your operating system? You might need to add `sudo`.

Comment: You have to add sudo to execute it or give that folder permission by chmod if you're using ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

try using sudo prefix and try run it again

Comment: Use comments for such short answers.!

Comment: saravanan can't comment till he gets at least 10 reputation. Plus there isn't a problem with a short answer if it's an ok answer (note I'm not familiar with npm so I don't know if it's a ok answer)